# php multidimensional array to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am working with a multidimensional array that looks like this

String

```
array(
  array(
[0] => 37.32830856
[1] => -122.01981483
[2] => 0x7fe48002b420<x-coredata:///Run/t061456B2-921C-41A0-BE37-B572DC61269C2603>
[3] => 2015-11-0920:30:25
[4] => 43594809345903485
  )

)
```

The database will have the following columns in the data base i need to fill,

latitude
longitude
coredata
time_stamp
unique_id

I know i need to look through my database but i can't find anything that tells me how to do it. Also my array can have 10 to even 200 arrays and it all needs to loop through it and store it in the database.

Can some one show me how this is done.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how you should structure the database table, or how to insert into an existing table with PHP?

Comment: you'd probably want a [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for the first level array to easily access the second level arrays and [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) particularly *"Example #3 INSERT prepared once, executed multiple times"*

Comment: also second level array elements `2` and `3` would probably generate a PHP error if you wasn't aware

Comment: i need to insert it in the mysql database. So i need to know how to loop through the array so it inputs it in the database. This is just a little too much for me. I need to learn how to do this.

Comment: i have tried so many solutions, noting works, and no i would rather learn it so i know what i am doing and can do it again whenever i need. I can also pay some one on fiver to do it, but i need to understand what is happening. sample code is the only way to learn how it works. thanks

Comment: Now people have given you examples, but generally you should show what you've tried and let people help you with your code. This isn't really the format for pure tutorials. There are about 1.000.000 other sites for that. Google "get started with php mysql" will give you a lot of those. This is just lazy.

Comment: not sure what your deal is, but if you would have tried google and you would not be a pro you would see what there is not really much decent explanation on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$mysqli` as your database connection, `$outerArray` is the name of your array containing the arrays of data and `yourTable` as your table name, try something like

```
foreach ($outerArray as $innerArray) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO yourTable (latitude, longitude, coredata, time_stamp, unique_id)
      VALUES('{$innerArray[0]}','{$innerArray[1]}','{$innerArray[2]}','{$innerArray[3]}','{$innerArray[4]}')";
    $mysqli->query($query);
```

}

Comment: i would like to thank every one for the help, I now understand that i was looking at much too complex solutions, but this little piece of code did the work and is quite easy to understand now that i see it at work. thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can make all the insertions in once using the following:

```
try {
    //Make your connection handler to your database
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$servername.";dbname=".$database, $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));

    $data = array(
        array('37.32830856', '-122.01981483', '0x7fe48002b420', '2015-11-0920:30:25', '43594809345'),
        array('42.32830856', '-10.01981483', 'adsfasd43345', '2015-10-0920:30:25', '454545151'),
    );

    $values = array(); //Prepared insert values
    $binds = array(); //Real values
    $i = 0;

    $temp = "INSERT INTO your_table VALUES ";

    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $values[] = ' (:latitude'.$i.', :longitude'.$i.', :coredata'.$i.', :time_stamp'.$i.', :unique_id'.$i.')';
        $binds[':latitude'.$i] = $value[0];
        $binds[':longitude'.$i] = $value[1];
        $binds[':coredata'.$i] = $value[2];
        $binds[':time_stamp'.$i] = $value[3];
        $binds[':unique_id'.$i] = $value[4];
        $i++;
    }
    $sql_query = $temp.implode(', ', $values).';'; //Create your sql_query for all your insertions

    echo $sql_query;
    var_dump($binds);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_query);
    $stmt->execute($binds);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Statement:

```
echo $sql_query;
```

Result:

```
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES 
(:latitude0, :longitude0, :coredata0, :time_stamp0, :unique_id0), 
(:latitude1, :longitude1, :coredata1, :time_stamp1, :unique_id1);
```

Statement:

```
var_dump($binds);
```

Result:

```
array (size=10)
    ':latitude0' => string '37.32830856' (length=11)
    ':longitude0' => string '-122.01981483' (length=13)
    ':coredata0' => string '0x7fe48002b420' (length=14)
    ':time_stamp0' => string '2015-11-0920:30:25' (length=18)
    ':unique_id0' => string '43594809345' (length=11)
    ':latitude1' => string '42.32830856' (length=11)
    ':longitude1' => string '-10.01981483' (length=12)
    ':coredata1' => string 'adsfasd43345' (length=12)
    ':time_stamp1' => string '2015-10-0920:30:25' (length=18)
    ':unique_id1' => string '454545151' (length=9)
```